# execute JDBC as400 group query gives error: A character, token, or clause is not valid or is missing

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange, sqlexception

I am trying to execute a query in java to AS400 and I receive the error below. 
I believe it has to do with grouping, and with assigned the aggregate column an alias:

```
SUM( ILHRS ) AS \"SumIlhrs\"
```

Am I perhaps not escaping the quotes correctly? I have tried the following with no success

```
SUM( ILHRS ) AS \"SumIlhrs\", ..,
SUM( ILHRS ) AS \'SumIlhrs\', ...
SUM( ILHRS ), ...
```

The query is tested and working.

```
String query = "SELECT ILER,PREN,SUM( ILHRS ) AS \"SumIlhrs\" FROM HRDBFA.PYPIL PYPIL, HRDBFA.PRPMS PRPMS WHERE PYPIL.ILEN = PRPMS.PREN AND ( ( ILFYR = 2013 "  +
" AND ILFMON = 9) AND PRGP IN( 'U55', '066', '088' )) GROUP BY ILER,PREN";
```

Error Message:

***SQLException: A character, token, or clause is not valid or is missing.***

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to have quotes around the alias at all.  Try without quotes.  Also, print out the value of `query` to see what the JDBC driver is seeing.

Comment: I tried  that as well, but get the same error. I printed the value of the query(below) and also copy /pasted into my query tool, and it worked. this is the value of the query:

SELECT ILER,PREN,SUM( ILHRS ) AS SumIlhrs FROM HRDBFA.PYPIL PYPIL, HRDBFA.PRPMS
PRPMS WHERE PYPIL.ILEN = PRPMS.PREN AND ( ( ILFYR = 2013  AND ILFMON = 9) AND PRGP IN( 'U55', '066', '088' )) GROUP BY ILER,PREN

Comment: The only reason to put the double quotes around the alias name is to make the result column name mixed case.  Otherwise the name will be translated to upper case.  I would not bother with them, unless you have some reason to want a mixed case name.

Comment: You need to post the complete stack trace as well as the code that throws the exception.  You may be looking in the wrong place if it works in your query tool. [Aside: That error message deserves a booby prize for being almost meaningless.  Whoever wrote the code that produces that message was just plain lazy]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to escape the double quotes.  In fact, as suggested by Jim Garrison, you don't need the double quotes around the assigned name at all.  Try

```
"SELECT ILER,PREN,SUM( ILHRS ) AS SumIlhrs FROM...
```

**EDIT**

DB2 on IBM i has two styles of names: System and SQL.  System naming would be `SELECT ILER,PREN,SUM( ILHRS ) AS SumIlhrs FROM HRDBFA/PYPIL PYPIL, HRDBFA/PRPMS PRPMS WHERE PYPIL.ILEN = PRPMS.PREN AND ( ( ILFYR = 2013 AND ILFMON = 9) AND PRGP IN( 'U55', '066', '088' )) GROUP BY ILER,PREN`  I'd be surprised that the JDBC driver is set for system naming, but it's possible.

Another thought: You're only using the correlation names in one place.  Either drop the correlation names altogether or qualify each column with the appropriate correlation name.  `SELECT ILER,PREN,SUM( ILHRS ) AS SumIlhrs FROM HRDBFA/PYPIL, HRDBFA/PRPMS WHERE ILEN = PREN AND ( ( ILFYR = 2013 AND ILFMON = 9) AND PRGP IN( 'U55', '066', '088' )) GROUP BY ILER,PREN`

Comment: Didn't seem to have an affect (I tried the other style, as well as dropping the corr. names).

Comment: it is working now. It appears it has to do with my defination of the db connection class I was using to connect and execute the query. I replaced it with a previous version and it works, but dont know the difference unfortunately (I delete it before looking).

Comment: It may have been due to do the naming mode specified in your connection string.

Comment: I would say best practice is to use system naming. If your system running IBM i 7.1, and is fairly up to date on PTF's (patches), then system naming now allows either schema.table or schema/table syntax, but has the advantage of using your library list for name resolution (ie. a search path list of schemas). This allows your code to run in various environments without making any changes.